# Set custom sms ringtone for single user

Tags: android, android-settings

I want to set custom ring while receiving sms from user like "Demo" .Is it possible to set custom ring for single user ? I am trying this but can not achieve my requirement

```
    final Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, "9801205808");
    final String[] projection = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY
    };
    final Cursor data = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, projection, null, null, null);
    data.moveToFirst();
    try {
        final long contactId = data.getLong(0);
        final String lookupKey = data.getString(1);
        final Uri contactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, lookupKey);
        if (contactUri == null) {
            return;
        }
        final String storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        final File file = new File(storage + "/AudioRecorder", "hello.mp4");
        final String value = Uri.fromFile(file).toString();

        final ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
        values.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, value);
        getContentResolver().update(contactUri, values, null, null);
    } finally {
        data.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to set Ringtone for a contact:

```
 Cursor c =...; // query contact cursor
    int dataIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Contacts._ID);
    String contactId = c.getString(dataIndex);
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Contacts.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, mRingtoneUri.toString());
    getContentResolver().update(uri, values, null, null);
```